# TypeError: 'Int64Index([], dtype='int64')' is an invalid key

Tags: python, pandas, function, class, typeerror

This class should be able to work with a given csv-file and the function is responsible to update the csv if the price of the input is lower. but i get a error-message if I work with self.df instead of defining the self.df to a df variable outside the loop.

The format of the csv-file is "City,IATA Code,Lowest Price" and a example input for the function could be "{'LTN': {'Lowest Price': 11}}"

```
import pandas

class DataManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.csv = pandas.read_csv("prices.csv")
        self.df = pandas.DataFrame(self.csv)

    def update_price_list(self, new_prices):
        data = pandas.DataFrame(new_prices).transpose()
        for entry in data.iterrows():
            index = self.df.index[self.df["IATA Code"] == "IST"]
            index_in_df = self.df.index[self.df["IATA Code"] == entry[0]]
            if self.df.at[index_in_df, "Lowest Price"] > float(entry[1]):
                self .df = self.df.at[index_in_df, "Lowest Price"] = float(entry[1])

DataManager().update_price_list({'LTN': {'Lowest Price': 11}})
```

The ERROR-Message outputs "TypeError: 'Int64Index([], dtype='int64')' is an invalid key"

if i define the Dataframe as varible in outside the for loop there is no problem,
but i feel like that is not the right way. How do i avoid this error?

Complete errormessage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Flori/PycharmProjects/Kurs-Python/Python-Course/6. Week/Day 38/Flight_price_finder/wtf.py", line 19, in <module>
    DataManager().update_price_list({'LTN': {'Lowest Price': 11}})
  File "C:/Users/Flori/PycharmProjects/Kurs-Python/Python-Course/6. Week/Day 38/Flight_price_finder/wtf.py", line 16, in update_price_list
    if self.df.at[index_in_df, "Lowest Price"] > float(entry[1]):
  File "C:\Users\Flori\PycharmProjects\Kurs-Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2275, in __getitem__
    return super().__getitem__(key)
  File "C:\Users\Flori\PycharmProjects\Kurs-Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2222, in __getitem__
    return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "C:\Users\Flori\PycharmProjects\Kurs-Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3579, in _get_value
    loc = engine.get_loc(index)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 82, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
TypeError: 'Int64Index([], dtype='int64')' is an invalid key
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error message as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: The "at" function expects a single row and/or column but "index_in_df" is an index because it is a part of the whole dataframe index. If you are sure that "index_in_df" only contains a single item (or you are only interested in the first item) you can use "index_in_df[0]" instead.

Comment: @MichaelButscher how did you include the import into the codesection?

Comment: Select all lines of code then click in the editor on the `{}` icon or indent all these lines with four (additional) spaces.